# How to use a cell to select which sheet is used in formulas

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In my spreadsheet, I had been adding values to a sheet named « Block1 » for a month. At the end of the month, I analysed this first sheet with an other sheet called « Analyse ».
At the end of the second month, I had another sheet with the same format as Block1 but with different values and named « Block2 ».
I am trying to keep up using the sheet Analyse for Block2 by adding a cell where I would write or select the sheet I want to analyse.

By adding some If clauses in every formula, it will work. However I would have to add each month a new if clause…[image: Sheet « Analyse » with a formula]
[image: A cell to select the studied sheet]

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ryj9jUSQmTEHs0ymScEvaBTF8VVyfJw0RSlAd4GxdPc/edit) is a link to a copy of my google sheet.

Comment: Add public sharing to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mmm, one option is to update every formula and add an indirect clause to each cell is referring. I don't know how much you've done so far

What I'd do in order not to modify everything you've done is to duplicate Block 1 tab as a backup, and modify the original one (the one to which the formulas are already working with) and modify it to become a kind of dashboard or mirror of the tab you want to analyse. A kind of auxiliary tab. Let's say you name it "Auxiliary"

Imagine you choose the tab to analyse in Analyse!B1, so in that auxiliary tab (ex- Block 1) I'll insert a formula in Auxiliary!A1

> =INDIRECT("'"&Analyse!B2&"'!A:Z") --> or the usual data range you have in each Block tab

This way each time you modify B1 all that Auxiliary sheet will update